# RouteCollection Querysting

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to define MapPageRoute on the application global.asax but my problem is that I can not route the specific URL to a physical file with a query string.

For example I want to redirect http://mysite.com/Apple to http://mysite.com/product.aspx?id=95.
What I managed to achieve so far is if a user ask for  ./Apple he will be redirected to ./product.aspx but I can not pass the query string.

Looking forward for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["Apple"] != null)
{
    int appleID = Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["Apple"]);
    Response.Redirect("~/product.aspx?id=" + appleID.ToString(), true); 
}
```

Comment: This means I have to have a page in between that do the redirect ?